# Option for chaning password by logged user

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I got simple login/register controller where user can create account and can signin.

There is my signin with roles

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      username: req.body.username
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found." });
      }

      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
      );

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          accessToken: null,
          message: "Wrong password!"
        });
      }

      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // 24 hours
      });

      var authorities = [];
      user.getRoles().then(roles => {
        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          authorities.push("ROLE_" + roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
        };
        res.status(200).send({
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          roles: authorities,
          accessToken: token
        });
      
      });
       
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

How can I allow user to change password?
I should check if user is logged in then get new password from user? But should I get also old password for compare or something? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your update password route need to be protected by jwt. It indentified authoririty and user who is changing the password.

Then, depend on your design, user need/not need enter the old password. At most of cases, user needs to enter old password when changing password case, and doesn't need old password on reset password case.

I suggest you reading document of JWT authentication. I think you don't understand what it is used for, what data it provides.

Comment: I already did it.
My route is protected because you must be logged in to change password. :)

Thank you